DALI DT-8 xy implementation
I have x and y values. I want to send that value to the DALI driver.
I got this image of commands from this answer.

As shown in the image command 224 is used for set temporary x-coordinate and 225 is used for set temporary y-coordinate.
Is it same commands I need to use or any other commands I need to use to send X and Y value of light?

These commands 224, 225, 226 are sufficient to set the colour values using x and y coordinates immediately but there are other commands where colour is a factor. Fade time, scenes, power on, system failure and up and down commands can also change the colour using x and y coordinates. Unfortunately a comprehensive answer would mean summarizing most of the IEC 62386-209 standard, which is the most complicated standard in the DALI series.
Table 14 lists the commands which apply to each color type, so for xy this list is 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 238, 243, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 255.

In addition to that, one has to use the "enable DT8" command as well, and there are special rules for the send-twice commands. I agree that implementing this correctly requires obtaining the full standard document.

I have values in terms of hexadecimal(0 to 65279).How can I send value to dali.if value is 0x616b,then I need to send 0.381 to driver.

You have to set the Most Significant Byte and the Least Significant Byte in the DTR1 and DTR registers as shown in the table before you send the 224/225 commands.

No need of conversion right.ccan i send direct value to dali driver?

You can’t send a 16-bit value like 0x616b to an 8-bit register.
